# Why data retrieved via Laravel Eloquent behavies this way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I do sth like this:

```
$data = Somedatabase::all();// and in my database, this is EMPTY
if ($data){
  die('not empty');
}else{
  die('empty);
}
```

the result, however is `not empty`, why is so? and if I change `die('not empty')` to `die($data)` if would gave me `[]`

So, my first question is `why it behaves this way?(showing a '[]')`

The reason I'm asking is cuz in my view, I wanna do this:

```
@if ($data)
  @foreach ($data as $tmp)
    {{$tmp}}
  @endforeach
@else
  <p>EMPTY!</p>
@end
```

but I can never got the "EMPTY!" and now I'm using a $flag to check so that when it's empty I can got the message, but I think there should be a better way, so, the second question is `what I suppose to do if I wanna get the "EMPTY!" message?`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Somedatabase:all()` *always* returns a eloquent collection object. Whether that object contains any data is another story.

The easiest way to check is either

```
if ($data->isEmpty()){
  die('empty');
}else{
  die('not empty);
}
```

or

```
if ($data->count()){
  die('not empty');
}else{
  die('empty);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the "count()" now for the $flag I've mention before, but the "isEmpty()" is just what I really want :)
And btw, would you please share with me how do you find out the isEmpty() method, because it seems that it's not in the doc, or am I missed sth? Thank you again :)

Comment: I look at the source code alot - there are a number of undocumented functions that can be quite useful. They are slowly been added to the documentation